# PHP simple whois script html form

Tags: php

Im just creating a simple tool in PHP what uses the built in whois command in linux and then echo's the response back to the user. Everything I have attempted has either failed or I have messed up somewhere.

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" name="cmd1">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
$cmd = $_POST['cmd1'];
echo "<pre>".shell_exec('whois ', $cmd)."</pre>";
?>
```

For me nothing happens, for the record I am new to PHP and I would like just a little expertise. Im the only one that is going to be using the script. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check whether a `POST` variable was submitted, so you don't try to run `whois` when you're first displaying the form. You should also escape the parameter to prevent command injection.

And you need to display the results inside the `<body>` of the HTML.

Another problem: you need to concatenate `'whois '` with the parameter, not pass them as separate arguments to `shell_exec` (it only takes one argument, and ignores the extra argument, so you were just executing the command `whois` with no domain).

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" name="cmd1">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['cmd1'])) {
    $cmd = $_POST['cmd1'];
    echo "<pre>".shell_exec('whois ' . escapeshellarg($cmd))."</pre>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Net_Whois](https://pear.php.net/package/Net_Whois/):

**Install:**

```
pear install Net_Whois
```

**Usage:**

```
<?php
require_once "Net/Whois.php";
$server = "whois.denic.de";
$query  = isset($_POST['cmd1']) ? $_POST['cmd1']  : 'phpcrawler.de'; 
$whois = new Net_Whois;
$data = $whois->query($query, $server);
echo $data;
?>
```